# Facebook OAuthException : Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get facebook access_token with curl. This is my code

```
$fields = array(
    'client_id'       => '**************',
    'client_secret'   => '**************',
    'code'            => '*******************',
    'redirect_uri'    => 'https://phpstack-140306-780547.cloudwaysapps.com/'
);
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($result);
```

And in the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" section it is same.

[Valid OAuth Redirect URIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScAUD.png)

My question is there anything wrong with the process? Maybe I am missing something. Can not figure it out yet. Need help badly. I am new to facebook API.

Comment: Well the question is, what did you use when you actually acquired the `code`? (Hard-coding that makes little sense.)

Comment: yes by hard coding.

Comment: That won’t work. These codes can only be used one time, and for a limited time after they were issued (couple if minutes only), for security reasons. You need to go through the proper login flow to get a fresh code, when you want to log a user in.

Comment: Ah.. ok. Just to be sure, after getting a fresh code would these snippets work?

Comment: it should, provided you specify the exact same redirect_uri value then, as was used in the login dialog call.